# Host ASP.NET Core API as a part of a BackgroundService's collection, without hardwire for IHost

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, background-service

I want to build a Windows Service project that, besides other responsibilities, based on the configuration can dynamically start and stop a self-hosted ASP.NET Core API instance.

All of the current examples where we host ASP.NET Core in Windows service rely on a developer to create an ASP.NET Core API project, and then, Nuget in the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` and call

`Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseWindowsService()`

as a part of the builder/build process.

However I would like to have a completely separated API that is either gets started or not based on the configuration. Thus, it's "plumbing" code for setting up the hostin should happen in an `ExecuteAsync` method of the `BackgroundService`, not be hard-coded along with the startup code.

Basically, I want "A service that hosts many background services, including the API one's", not "An API project that supports hosting in Windows service".

I am failing to find a good example on how this is achieved, e.g. "web stuff" is instantiated from a `BackgroundService`, not from app root code in Program.cs.

Any hint on how to achieve this would be appreciated.